# Google Script to Auto Fil Google Doc (convert textstring to currency)

Tags: google-apps-script

First time posting so thanks in advance.

I have a google sheets that has 15 to 20 currency fields that I have a script to auto fill to a google doc.  The snippet of code I am interesting in is how to convert tags such as {{Price1}} and {{Total1}} to be displayed as $#,###.00 rather than what is being displayed now as ##

I'm sure the answer is simple but ready to put my head thru a wall trying to figure out a solution.

```
//Start processing each spreadsheet row
rows.forEach(function(row, index){
//Here we check if this row is the headers, if so we skip it
if (index === 0) return;
//Here we check if a document has already been generated by looking at 'Document Link', if 
so we skip it
if (row[0]) return;
//Using the row data in a template literal, we make a copy of our template document in our 
destinationFolder
const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Invoice #:${row[2]}, ${row[1]} Invoice 1` , 
destinationFolder)
//Once we have the copy, we then open it using the DocumentApp
const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId())
//All of the content lives in the body, so we get that for editing
const body = doc.getBody();
//In this line we do some friendly date formatting, that may or may not work for you locale
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[3]).toLocaleDateString();



//In these lines, we replace our replacement tokens with values from our spreadsheet row
body.replaceText('{{Invoice Name}}', row[1]);
body.replaceText('{{Invoice}}', row[2]);
body.replaceText('{{Date}}', friendlyDate);
body.replaceText('{{Bill To}}', row[4]);
body.replaceText('{{Attn}}', row[5]);
body.replaceText('{{Bill Address}}', row[6]);
body.replaceText('{{Bill City}}', row[7]);
body.replaceText('{{Bill Telephone}}', row[8]);
body.replaceText('{{Project}}', row[9]);
body.replaceText('{{Project #}}', row[10]);
body.replaceText('{{Project Address}}', row[11]);
body.replaceText('{{Project City}}', row[12]);
body.replaceText('{{Project Telephone}}', row[13]);
body.replaceText('{{Desc1}}', row[14]);
body.replaceText('{{Qty1}}', row[15]);
    body.replaceText('{{Price1}}',Utilities.formatString("$%.2f",row[16]);
 body.replaceText('{{Total1}}', row[17]);
 body.replaceText('{{Desc2}}', row[18]);
 body.replaceText('{{Qty2}}', row[19]);
const url = doc.getUrl();
sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1).setValue(url)
 })
```

Comment: This is just my guess. Although, unfortunately I cannot see your whole script and your Spreadsheet, for example, when the cells of your Spreadsheet are like `$#,###.00` and you are retrieving the values using `setValues`, when you modify `setValues` to `getDisplayValues`, is that the result you expect? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to convert numbers in your own format?
Try replace:

```
body.replaceText('{{Price1}}',row[16]);
```

With:

```
body.replaceText('{{Price1}}',Utilities.formatString("YOUR FORMAT HERE", row[16]));
```

For dollars, `"$%'.2f"` will work.
see also:
[Utilities.formatString](https://sites.google.com/site/gasgaidobukku/utilities/formatstring), [Printf Format](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet/)

added on 2021/05/25:

In that case, I would make a new function to do that. It also makes your code tidy.
Something like:

```
myConvert(format, value){
  if (value == 0){ // or any appropriate condition
    return "null"; // or whatever
  }else{
    return Utilities.formatString(format, value)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  Last question...how do I send in a null value to have the field display as null?  For example, Price1 might be $12.20 but Price2 might be $0.00 so rather than showing $0.00 on google docs, I want the field to display as null since the google docs will be an invoice template and I don't want $0.00 all over the place.

If I pass in the value as "", I get the following error

ypeError: value.toFixed is not a function
demuxes_.f @ format_string.js.gs:113
replacerDemuxer @ format_string.js.gs:212
formatString_ @ format_string.js.gs:215

Comment: In that case, I would make a new function to do that. It also makes your code tidy.
Something like:
`
  myConverrt(format, value){
  if (value == 0){ // or any appropriate condition
    return "null"; // or whatever
  }else{
    return Utilities.formatString(format, value)
  }
}
`

Comment: Looks like I'm still getting errors.  Can I ask if this snippet looks correct?  body.replaceText('{{Total2}}', row[21]);
    body.replaceText('{{Price3}}', row[24]);
 
  })
  
}
 function myConvert(format, value){
  if (value == 0){ // or any appropriate condition
    return ""; // or whatever
  }else{
    return Utilities.formatString(format, value)
    const url = doc.getUrl();
    
    sheet.getRange(index + 1, 1).setValue(url)
  }
 }